# Getting a string in textfield before a specific string in the textfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

So my textfield has the following text. `@"A big Tomato is red."`

I want to get the word before **"is".**

When I type

```
  NSString *someString = [[textfield componentsSeparatedByString:@"is"]objectAtIndex:0];
```

I always get `"A big Tomato"` instead of just `"Tomato"`. In the app people will type things before `"is"` so I need to always get the string before `"is"`. I would appreciate any help I can get. *Warning,

This is a very difficult problem.

Comment: Why don't you split the result "A big Tomato" by space end take the last entry which will be "Tomato"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
NSString *str = @"A big tomato is red";
NSArray *arr = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
int index = [arr indexOfObject:@"is"];
if(index > 1)
    NSString *str_tomato = arr[index-1];
else
    //"is" is the first word of sentence
```

as per [yvesleborg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/915467/yvesleborg)'s comment

Comment: test this with "is a big tomato"

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
NSString *value = @"A big Tomato is red.";
NSArray *array = [value componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
if ([array containsObject:@"is"]) {
    NSInteger index = [array indexOfObject:@"is"];
    if (index != 0) {
        NSString *word = [array objectAtIndex:index - 1];
        NSLog(@"%@", word);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 NSString *string = @"A big Tomato is red.";
    if ([string rangeOfString:@"is"].location == NSNotFound) {
      NSLog(@"string does not contain is");
    } else {
      NSLog(@"string contains is!");
    }
```